# Faster way to perform an If statement

Tags: excel, performance, if-statement, vba

Is there a faster way to run the below code? the "hr" sheet has 24000 rows and it takes about 30+ minutes to run this simple query.

```
Sub populateHRData17()
'APAC
Set report = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
Set hr = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("HR_Report")
Set apac = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("APAC_L_R")

For x = 2 To report.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If report.Cells(x, 1) = "" Then
    End If
Next x


For i = 2 To hr.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  For j = 2 To apac.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If apac.Cells(j, 2) = hr.Cells(i, 3) Then
       report.Cells(x, 1) = apac.Cells(j, 2)


 x = x + 1
    End If

Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Use variant arrays to store the data and loop those.  Limit the number of times that vba needs to reference data on the worksheet and you will see a great improvement.

Comment: What is the purpose of the 1st loop, I can't see any logic in it.

Comment: Instead of using that 1st loop to find the last row in "Report" sheet, you can use. `Sheets("Report").Cells(Sheets("Report").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = apac.Cells(j, 2).value`

Comment: Ill look into the variant array. Still kind of new to this thanks!

Dave i tried the code you gave me but im getting an "Application-defined or object -defined error"